# Correct way of keeping user session alive

Tags: javascript, session, server

I'm looking at creating a script that does the following:

*Every X minutes*, check if the user has typed something. If they have, then keep their server-side session alive (via AJAX call to some innocuous action server-side). If they have not, then do nothing.

Here's what I came up with, but I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing it:

```
// This variable will keep track of when the user has typed.
var b = false;

$(document).on('keyup', function () {
    console.log("Setting b to true.");
    b = true;
});

setInterval(func, 5000);

function func()
{
    if (b == true) {
        console.log("Keeping alive!");
        // Make AJAX call here.
    }
    b = false;
    console.log("  Setting b to false.");
}
```

I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Why do you need an interval at all? Surely just listening for a keypress event is sufficient?

Comment: Also, avoid `setInterval`, and use nested `setTimeout`s instead.

Comment: Is the 5 second interval really necessary? A "heartbeat" every x minutes should be enough. And maybe add `mousemove` to the event list.

Comment: The **5 seconds** is just for the example. In reality it could be 5 minutes, 7 minutes, etc..

Comment: @BenM The reason I put in the interval is because I don't want to make an AJAX call _every time_ the user presses a key.
Also, is there a reason for using nested `setTimeout`'s?

Comment: @MaxJacob yes, what if your AJAX hasn't called back? Then you are triggering multiple AJAX requests at the same time.

Comment: @BenM Please correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't a `setInterval` just a thing that loops constantly at a set rate? So basically every (in the case of the example) 5 seconds, an AJAX call is made (as long as the user types something). I don't care about the return value of the AJAX call because I'm just making the call to keep the user's server-side session alive. Does `setInterval` care about the return value?

Answer (score 0):

Several years ago, Paul Irish did an implementation of an idle timer in jQuery.
(Based on something from Nicholas C. Zakas in YUI [1]).  You can see his write up at [2] and see the maintained github repo at [3]

The approach is similar to you snippet, event listeners for whatever constitutes "activity",and, to prevent inundating the server with events, some timer of when to ping the server. You can see in their code what special exceptions they encountered and for which events they listened.

Using the idle timer from Paul Irish, Eric Hynds had a nice write up and implementation of a jQuery plugin to notify users of when their sessions are about expire. Unfortunately that article is gone. The code appears to be maintained at [4]

[1] https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2009/06/02/detecting-if-the-user-is-idle-with-javascript-and-yui-3/

[2] https://www.paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/

[3] https://github.com/thorst/jquery-idletimer

[4] https://github.com/ericlbarnes/jquery-idle-timeout